# Ubuntu 20.04 - No wifi adapter found DELL

Tags: wireless

I know there are many questions about this, but no one works for me.

I have been more than a week testing blogs, github and forum solutions, actually I really don't know what I have installed, blacklisted and created to try to get back my wifi adapter.

Problem started after I connect my ipad to my laptop.

Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Inspiron 3521

Kernel release:

```
5.4.0-37-generic
```

If I throw this line:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

Output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If I throw this line

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Output:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic
```

If I throw this line:

```
grep wl /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

Output:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
/etc/modprobe.d/RTL810xE.conf:options RTL810xE fwlps=N
```

BIOS:

```
secure boot disable
load legacy option Enable
Boot list option legacy
```

Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

if I throw  `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`:

```
wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: So does `sudo modprobe wl` work now? The `wl.ko` is definitely there now. Reboot and Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: man, please, give me your contact, you solve the problem, you are an amazing person, an amazing profesional, I really need to THANK YOU with some donation, i do not have words for you, you fix it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The driver is installed it is shown here:

```
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

`wl` is the correct driver for this adapter.

But the problem it is not in use. The reason may be that Secure Boot is enabled in UEFI settings, or it is blacklisted.

Check if Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI aka BIOS. If that doesn't help, run

```
grep wl /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

and look if `wl` is blacklisted somewhere.

If that doesn't help, reinstall `wl` by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: I reinstalled, it doesn't work

Comment: What did you re-install? I didn't suggest to reinstall anything. Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: secure boot is disabled. just letting know, that even reinstalling my OS wifi adapter is not found. 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and post the output to your question.

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source works for my Dell Vostro 3446.

Comment: @SandeshYadav I'm tagging you because you use Dell Vostro 3446. I am facing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1892747 . Apparently bugs like these are modal specific. If you are facing this too, can you click "This bug affects me too" and add your system info by typing `apport-collect 1892747` in the terminal. The bug won't be confirmed unless more users face it.

Comment: on running sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source, I am getting an error: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: You need to be connected to internet.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue. came across this ticket. But for my device(Dell Inspiron 3543 & Unbuntu 20.04)

Kernel : 5.8.0-34-generic

BIOS : Secure boot disable

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Kernel module wl was missing

Tried : `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

but still Kernel module `wl`  was not installed, nor was my wifi working

`bcma` module was blacklisted. commented it in the `blacklist.conf` file, but no luck with the wifi.

Finally, this helped [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1906745]

**SOLUTION**

1. sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
2. sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms
   broadcom-sta-common
3. reboot

I'm not expert in this field, but this solution worked for me.

Comment: Worked at my end, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many other solutions, but nothing worked for me.

In my case, I unchecked and re-checked WLAN option in my Dell Probook BIOS. I think some update to my BIOS messed up the things. After I rechecked the WLAN option, Wifi came in Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score -1):

I also face the problem.I solved this via "Additional Drivers" tab in "Software&update". Here already selected "Do not use the device"
Now u select " Using 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source(proprietary)" click "Apply changes"