# No Wi-Fi Adapter found on Ubuntu 22.04 on Alienware M15 R17

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, alienware

I've just bought an Alienware M15 R7 and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it and Wi-Fi is not working. I tried to follow multiple solutions, but none of them worked for me.

I'm getting the message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhGdj.png)

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
giorge@giorge-Alienware-m15-R7:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:6235284000-6235287fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: enp58s0
       version: 06
       serial: 04:bf:1b:17:47:34
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.17.0-1020-oem duplex=full firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 ip=192.168.0.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:8f100000-8f10ffff memory:8f110000-8f113fff
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**uname -mrs**

```
Linux 5.17.0-1020-oem x86_64
```

**grep wl /etc/modprobe.d/***

```
/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf:# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with ssb
/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf:install wl /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl $CMDLINE_OPTS
/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf:# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with the following modules:
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

And there's no Wireless driver in Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGmUK.png)

I've tried the following solutions:

1. rfkill unblock all;
2. sudo apt-get reinstall network-manager;
3. [ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249907/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell)

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Adding output of **lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | grep iwl**

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1672]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0b54]
--
0000:3a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:3000] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller [1028:0b54]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

**UPDATE 2**

Adding output of **sudo dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[    2.038814] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.038815] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    2.232493] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol iwl_mei_is_connected (err -2)
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: a wireless usb adapter should do the trick

Comment: @Jeremy31 I've added it!

Comment: I would like to use the existing wireless adapter, once it's a notebook.

Comment: I think @Jeremy31 meant to ask for: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Just added it!

Comment: I would be very surprised to find that you actually needed backport. I also suspect that backport is not compatible with your 5.17 kernel version. I suggest that you do: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and show us a new version of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Is this 5.17 kernel actually a 5.17 OEM kernel?

Comment: Guys I had the same issue, the same versions and the fully equal problem
I have solved this like this: (updated my kernel from 6.2 to 6.4 and wifi works fine now)
https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-change-default-kernel-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/